# How to randomizeRange in python with google sheets api?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to run this code:

```py
requests = {
    'randomizeRange': {
        'range': {
            'ranges': ['Sheet1!A3:A32']
        }
    }
}
request = sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=sheet_id, body=requests)
r = request.execute()
print(r)
```

But I get this error:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "randomizeRange": Cannot find field.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: And google disc about randomRange https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#RandomizeRangeRequest

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use RandomizeRangeRequest of Sheets API using googleapis for python.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the request body is `{"requests": [{"randomizeRange": {"range": {,,,}}}]}`.
- From your script, I thought that `sheet` might be `service.spreadsheets()`.
- And also, the range is required to be GridRange.

  - When the a1Notation of `Sheet1!A3:A32` is converted to the GridRange, it becomes as follows.

    ```
      "range": {
          "sheetId": sheet_id, # This is the sheet ID of "Sheet1".
          "startRowIndex": 2,
          "endRowIndex": 32,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
      }
    ```

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please set your Spreadsheet ID
sheet_id = "###"  # Please set your sheet ID. In your script, please set the sheet ID of "Sheet1".

service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds) # Please use your script here.
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
requests = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "randomizeRange": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": 2,
                    "endRowIndex": 32,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1,
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=requests).execute()
```

- When this script is run, the cells "A3:A32" of "Sheet1" are randomized.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RandomizeRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#randomizerangerequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#gridrange)